# Flutter : InitState not being called in the beggining

Tags: flutter

This is my initstate function :
I am getting my path from a collection and proceeding. The idea is to get the data into those arrays, and I have verified that they are working. But the problem is, the arrays finish getting set only after the later function is called. In other words, the later function is getting executed even before initstate() is over, and instead `notFound` is being returned. Please help

```
@override

  Future<void> initState()  {
    super.initState();
    print("users/" + widget.state + "/" + widget.city);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(
        "users/" + widget.state + "/" + widget.city);
    db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      print("values " + values.toString());
      values.forEach((key, values) {
        print("39 : " + key);
        count = count + 1;                         // Count value incremented every time
        addressArr.add(values["address"]);
        nameArr.add(values["name"]);
        phoneArr.add(values["phone"]);
        cityArr.add(values["city"]);
        stateArr.add(values["state"]);
        //idArr.add(at.split(" ")[2]);
        print(addressArr[0]);
        print(nameArr[0]);
      }
      );
    }).then((_) {});
  }
```

And this function is supposed to get called after that :

```
Future<Widget> getRecordView()  {
    int i = 0;
    print(" Data : ");
    print(nameArr);
      var items = List<SearchRecord>.generate(count, (index) =>
          SearchRecord(
            name: nameArr[index],
            type: typeArr[index],
            address: addressArr[index],
            state: stateArr[index],
            phone: phoneArr[index],
            city: cityArr[index],
            //id: idArr[index],
          ));
      var listItems = items;
      if (count == 0) {
        return notFound(context);       // THIS ONE IS GETTING RETURNED 
       }
      var listview = ListView.builder(
          itemCount: count,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return listItems[index];
          }
      );
      return Future.value(listview);
  }
```

Comment: `initState` return type is `void` not `Future<void>`. If you set it `Future<void>`, the function will not be overridden.

So use the `FutureBuilder` for future values. I recommend to you [FutureBuilder: Widget of the Week video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ek8ZPdWj4Qo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put everything you need to do insided `initState` in another function:

```
Future<void> callback(){
print("users/" + widget.state + "/" + widget.city);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(
        "users/" + widget.state + "/" + widget.city);
    db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      print("values " + values.toString());
      values.forEach((key, values) {
        print("39 : " + key);
        count = count + 1;                         // Count value incremented every time
        addressArr.add(values["address"]);
        nameArr.add(values["name"]);
        phoneArr.add(values["phone"]);
        cityArr.add(values["city"]);
        stateArr.add(values["state"]);
        //idArr.add(at.split(" ")[2]);
        print(addressArr[0]);
        print(nameArr[0]);
      }
      );
    }).then((_) {});
}
```

then call it in the `initState`:

```
void initState(){
super.initState();
callback();
}
```